# How to remove empty lists from list using scala?

Tags: list, scala

I have following list structure -

```
List(List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List({"esx":"192.168.20.52","vm":" naa.60a9800042704577762b45634476337a ","datastore":"","vNic":"","portGroupVLan":"","vSwitch":"","physicalNic":"","lunName":"lun_30102014_101347)","writeIops":44998,"readIops":1635,"latency":47008,"serialNumber":"BpEwv+EcDv3z","usedSize":0,"totalSize":4,"availableSize":4,"throughput":null}, (), ()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List((), (), ()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List((), (), ()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List(()), List((), (), ()))
```

I want to remove all empty lists from above .
I want output as -

```
List({"esx":"192.168.20.52","vm":" naa.60a9800042704577762b45634476337a ","datastore":"","vNic":"","portGroupVLan":"","vSwitch":"","physicalNic":"","lunName":"lun_30102014_101347)","writeIops":44998,"readIops":1635,"latency":47008,"serialNumber":"BpEwv+EcDv3z","usedSize":0,"totalSize":4,"availableSize":4,"throughput":null})
```

How do I get above output by using scala??

Comment: Flatten it! That will remove the empty lists whilst collapsing the structure by one dimension.

Answer (score 2):

If your input is like that, i.e. you only have list(list(list())) depth, a double call to flatten will solve it.

```
val x = yourList
x.flatten.flatten
```

if your list has empty lists at various depths, you need to constantly flatten until you reach a fixed point:

```
val x = yourList
var y = x.flatten
var z = y.flatten
while (y != z) {
   y = z
   z = z.flatten
y
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: But I want only non empty list only... Can you see my expected output and input given please

Comment: Flattening removes empty lists:

List(List(), List(1)).flatten == List(1)

I assume that your actual code is not List(()) but List(List()), otherwise you don't have empty lists, you have lists filled with a single instance of the Unit type (VERY different thing).

Comment: your while loop will never typecheck.

Comment: You are right. My bad. Can you edit my response / add a response that does the same thing but with type check passing?